# Error with copy list in C, in new list

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010

I have a problem with list in C. I have to copy the value of `list l1` (in new `list l2`) where: `l1->e.numero_volte > occ`.

The code:

```
list seconda_lista(list l2,list l1, int occ) {
    element temp;
    if(l1!=NULL)
    {
        if(l1->e.numero_volte>occ)
        {
            temp.numero_volte=l1->e.numero_volte;
            strcpy(temp.parola,l1->e.parola);
            l2=cons(l2,temp);
            l2=l2->next;
        }
        seconda_lista(l2,l1,occ);
    }
}
```

But the program crashes. How can I solve this problem?

**EDIT**

I have changed the code, but it doesn't start.

```
list cons(list l,element el)
{
    list temp;
    temp=(NODO*)malloc(sizeof(NODO));
    temp->e=el;
    temp->next=l;

    return temp;
}

list insord(list l, element el)
{
    if(l==NULL)
    {
        return l=cons(l,el);
    }
    else
    {
        if(strcmp(l->e.parola,el.parola)>0)
        {
            return l=cons(l,el);
        }
        else
        {
            l->next=insord(l->next,el);
        }
        return l;
    }
}

list seconda_lista(list l2,list l1, int occ) 
{
    element temp;

    if(l1 != NULL)
    {
        if(l1->e.numero_volte > occ)
        {
            temp.numero_volte=l1->e.numero_volte;
            strcpy(temp.parola,l1->e.parola);
            l2=insord(l2,temp);
        }

        seconda_lista(l2,l1->next,occ);
    }
}
```

Comment: You may need to check `if (l2->next != NULL)` before moving ahead to copy next element.

Comment: You might have more luck here with identifiers in english (I am trying to write this without sounding arrogant, sorry if I failed).

Answer (score 0):

I have change but it's doesn't start

```
list cons(list l,element el){    
    list temp;
    temp=(NODO*)malloc(sizeof(NODO));
    temp->e=el;
    temp->next=l;

    return temp;    
}    

list insord(list l, element el){

    if(l==NULL){    
        return l=cons(l,el);
    }
    else{       
        if(strcmp(l->e.parola,el.parola)>0){    
            return l=cons(l,el);
        }
        else{    
            l->next=insord(l->next,el);
        }

        return l;    
    }    
}

list seconda_lista(list l2,list l1, int occ) {    
    element temp;    
    if(l1 != NULL){

    if(l1->e.numero_volte > occ) {           
        temp.numero_volte=l1->e.numero_volte;
        strcpy(temp.parola,l1->e.parola);

        l2=insord(l2,temp);    
    }

    seconda_lista(l2,l1->next,occ);

    }    
}
```

Comment: Edit your post, not use an answer.